# Why find_elements_by_tag_name("span") does not work inside gmail inbox but works in sign in page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

## I am using below code to find all elements with span tag in the web page:

```
def find_element(arg_drv, arg_tag_name = "span", arg_text = "test"):

    print("INFO: Tag name to find: '" + arg_tag_name + "'")

    print("INFO: Text of tag to find: '" + arg_text + "'")

    all_children_by_tag = arg_drv.find_elements_by_tag_name(arg_tag_name)

    print("INFO: Number of elements with tag ' " + arg_tag_name + "': "+ str(len(all_children_by_tag)))

    for child_ele in all_children_by_tag:
        print("INFO: Element text : " + child_ele.text)     
        if child_ele.text ==  arg_text:
            self.lg.log_msg("INFO: Element with text : " + child_ele.text + " found")
            return True
    return False
```

This fails and I get chrome stopped working error message

## find_element(drv, "span", "Forgot email?") function works when I use at the sign in page and returns all the relevant tags. Below are the tags

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Tag name to find: 'span'

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Text name of tag to find: 'Forgot email?'

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Number of elements with tag ' span': 11

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Link with text :

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Link with text :

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Link with text :

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Link with text :

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Link with text :

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Link with text :

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Link with text :

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Link with text : Forgot email?

23/04/2018-01:43:57 INFO: Link with text : Forgot email? found

## Issue

After logging into gmail, find_element(drv, "span", "test") fails. Function call never completes or there is a "Chrome driver stopped working" error message

Comment: Code trials and relevant HTML please

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
drv = webdriver.Chrome( "chromedriver.exe")
#Code for login
drv.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")

Comment: Instead of a comment update the main question with your code trials, relevant HTML and error stack trace along with the _Manual Steps_ you are trying to _Automate_.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved after I updated to ChromeDriver 2.38 :)

Its still puzzling for me as to why UI actions would work in the sign in page and chromedriver stopped working after sign in